# Error PDO PHP Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente codigo para una conexion y un insert en una base de datos mysql con php:

```
class ApptivaDB{ 
   private $tipo_de_base = 'mysql';
   private $host = 'localhost';
   private $nombre_de_base = 'mibd';
   private $usuario = 'miusuario';
   private $contrasena = 'mipass';
   public $conexion; 

   public function __construct() {

    // Setting Database Source Name (DSN)
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mibd';
        // Setting options
        $options = array (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // Making the connection to the database
        try {
            $this->conexion = new PDO($dsn, 'miusuario', 'mipass', $options); 
            return $this->conexion;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            print_r( $e->getMessage());
        }

   }

    public function insertar($estado_llamada,$campania){
        $consulta = $this->conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO registros_forms (estado_llamada,campania) 
            VALUES(:estado_llamada,:campania)');
        //paramettos
        $consulta->bindParam(':estado_llamada',$estado_llamada);
        $consulta->bindParam(':campania',$campania);
    
        $consulta->execute();
   }
   public function CloseConnection(){
     $this->conexion=null;
    } 
 }
```

Asi lo llamo

```
require_once "config_db.php";
$registros = new ApptivaDB();
$u=$registros->insertar($estado_llamada_f,$campania_f);
$registros->CloseConnection();
```

el problema es que siempre obtengo el siguiente error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

no se que podria estar fallando.

Comment: Creo que deberías replantear tu clase que maneja la conexión. 1. Generalmente no se retorna ningún objeto desde el constructor. 2. Tu clase no extiende de PDO y eso te dificultará el uso de las funciones propias de PDO en la instancia que crees de la misma. Por lo pronto, puedes quitar esto del constructor, pues no tiene sentido: `return $this->conexion;` Lo que dice el mensaje de error es que `$registros` es nulo. ¿El archivo donde lo usas está en la misma carpeta que `config_db.php`?

Comment: Hola, ya puse class ApptivaDB extends PDO, y quite el return pero sigo obteniendo el mismo el error, si todo esta en una sola carpeta, antes tenia el inserte y la conexion únicamente con mysqli y funcionaba, pero quise implementar con pdo por temas de seguridad, pero me sale siempre ese error.

Comment: Ya. Si ahora la clase extiende de PDO, pon la consulta así: `$consulta = $this->prepare('INSERT INTO registros_forms (estado_llamada,campania) 
            VALUES(:estado_llamada,:campania)');` O sea, ahí `$this` representa en sí una conexión PDO por cuanto la clase extiende de PDO.

Comment: Ah, otra cosa, para conectar tienes que llamar a la clase padre (o sea a PDO), tienes que poner la conexión así: `parent::__construct($dsn, 'miusuario', 'mipass', $options);`  **simplemente eso**, sin `new PDO` ni nada. Me refiero a cuando conectas, en el `try`

Comment: Verifica que el nombre de la base de datos sea el correcto, asi como los demas parametros que estas utilizando.